# Blog page showing same as homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm trying to have my posts post on another page(blog) and my 'home' page display as my front page. Both pages have their own templates assigned to them (home for home, blog for blog).

In the Reading settings, I've set front page as home, posts page as blog. But when I go to url.com/blog, it displays the same template as my home page. I'm not sure why it won't display my two blog posts.

In my home.php template, I have the following code, could this be the issue?

```
<!-- Display featured images -->
    <?php 
        $args = array('post_type'=> 'page');
        query_posts( $args );
    ?>

<!-- Get featured images -->
    <div class="main-thumb left">
        <?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post(); 
            ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="tint">
                            <div class="overlay caps">
                                <?php 
                                    echo(types_render_field("top-overlay", array("output"=>"html")));
                                ?>
                                <?php 
                                    echo(types_render_field("bottom-overlay", array("output"=>"html")));
                                ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .OVERLAY-->

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .TINT-->
                    </a>
                </li>
        <?php
                } 
            } 
        ?>
    </div> <!-- end .MAIN-THUMB-->
```

Comment: Give it a try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

home.php will be used as the home page no matter what according to the template hierarchy:

1. WordPress first determines whether it has a static front page. If a static front page has been set, then WordPress loads that page according to the page template hierarchy.
2. If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a template file called home.php and uses it to generate the requested page.

Comment: Okay, so there's no harm in me leaving the home page as "home" in my reading settings?

Comment: Have you created a page template for "blogs", published it and made sure it loaded correctly?

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize this. Also didn't know I had to actually add in code to the template.